# Question about the prime factors of a binomial coefficient

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Why is it that if $p$ is greater than $4n/5$, but less or equal to $n$, then $p$ does not divide $\binom{4n}{3n}$?

Comment: How many times does a factor $p$ occur in each of the factorials $(4n)!,\, (3n)!,\, n!$? (And we need $n > 2$.)

Comment: In $(4n)!$: 4 times, because $4p\le4n$, in $(3n)!$ - 3 times, as $3p\le3n$... In $n!$ - 1 time, as $p\le n$... So what? I am right?

Comment: Get rid of the "maybe" ;)

Comment: And now... the ocurrences of $p$ in the numerator and denominator are reducing? Since $4p$ divided by $3p+p$ is equal to 1? Got rid of "maybe" ;P

Comment: Yes, the occurrences of $p$ in the numerator and denominator cancel. [The special case $n = p = 3$ isn't quite caught by that argument because then we have in the numerator and the denominator an occurrence of $3p$ each, so the counts then are $5,4,1$, but everything cancels out again. For $n = p = 2$, we have $\binom{8}{6} = 28$, which is divisible by $p$.]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For $p\neq 2,3$

$p>\frac{4n}{5}$ implies $5p>4n$. Telling us $p$ apears $4$ with power $4$ in $4n!$.

On the other hand $p$ appears at least once in $n!$ since $p<n$ and at least three times in $3n!$ since $3p<3n$

Hence $\binom{4n}{3n}=\frac{(4n)!}{(3n)!n!)}$ is not a multiple of $p$.

If $p=2$ since $p>\frac{4n}{5}$ we must have $n=2$ or $1$ and if $p=3$ for the same reason we must have $n=1,3$ or $3$ and all seem to check out.